# Linked List in thread?

Tags: c, linked-list, pthreads

I've written a C script where I attempt to receive NTP packets and add them to a linked list which then sorts it by number of NTP packets received per IP.

Using the `checkInList()` command seems to work fine in the test in `main()` but compares the wrong ip when it is called in `recievethread()`.

Expected output:

```
[ (187.1.160.84:31) (255.255.255.255:400) (8.8.8.8:0) (192.168.2.1:0)  ]
```

Meaning that we received 400 packets from 255.255.255.255 0 from 8.8.8.8 and so on.

Real output:

```
[ (187.1.160.84:431) ]
```

What happens is the packet count keeps going up but the ip just changes to the most recent instead of adding a new one.

Code:

```
struct node  
{
    char *ip;
    int count;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *current = NULL;

void printInList()
{
    struct node *ptr = head;
    printf("\n[ ");

    //start from the beginning
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("(%s:%d) ", ptr->ip, ptr->count);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    printf(" ]");
}


int length()
{
    int length = 0;
    struct node *current;

    for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    {
        length++;
    }

    return length;
}
void sort(){

    int i, j, k, tempKey, tempData ;
    struct node *current;
    struct node *next;

    int size = length();
    k = size ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < size - 1 ; i++, k-- ) {
        current = head ;
        next = head->next ;

        for ( j = 1 ; j < k ; j++ ) {

            if ( current->count < next->count ) {
                tempData = current->count ;
                current->count = next->count;
                next->count = tempData ;

                tempKey = current->ip;
                current->ip = next->ip;
                next->ip = tempKey;
            }

            current = current->next;
            next = next->next;                        
        }
    }
}

void insertInList(char *ipaddr, int count)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Inserting: %s:%d\t", ipaddr, count);
#endif
   //create a link
   struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

   link->ip = ipaddr;
   link->count = count;
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Inserted: %s:%d\t", link->ip, link->count);
#endif
   //point it to old first node
   link->next = head;

   //point first to new first node
   head = link;
}

int checkInList(const char *string)
{
    /* 
    If 1 returned means we found it
    If 0 Means we didnt find it 
    */
    struct node *ptr = head;

    //start from the beginning
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Comparing %s and %-20s", ptr->ip, string);
#endif
        if(strcmp(ptr->ip, string) == 0) {
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("Adding count: %s->%d\n", ptr->ip, ptr->count);
#endif
            ptr->count++;
            return 0;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Returning 1\n");
#endif
    return 1;
}

void *recievethread()
{
    int saddr_size, data_size, sock_raw;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    struct in_addr in;

    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536);
    sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_UDP);
    if(sock_raw < 0)
    {
        printf("Socket Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1) {
        saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
        data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&saddr , &saddr_size);
        if(data_size < 0) {
            printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)buffer;
        if(iph->protocol == 17)
        {
            unsigned short iphdrlen = iph->ihl*4;
            struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr*)(buffer + iphdrlen);
            unsigned char* payload = buffer + iphdrlen + 8;
            if(ntohs(udph->source) == 123) {
                int body_length = data_size - iphdrlen - 8;
                if (body_length > 47) {
                    if(checkInList(inet_ntoa(saddr.sin_addr)) == 1) {
                        insertInList(inet_ntoa(saddr.sin_addr), 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    close(sock_raw);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t listenthread;
    pthread_create( &listenthread, NULL, &recievethread, NULL);

    // Some tests
    if(checkInList("192.168.2.1") == 1) {
        insertInList("192.168.2.1", 0);
    }
    if(checkInList("8.8.8.8") == 1) {
        insertInList("8.8.8.8", 0);
    }

    while(1) {
        sort();
        printInList();
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if it doesn't make sense and feel free to redirect me to another thread if you think it will help me.

Comment: You need to ensure that two threads don't try to access your data simultaneously in a way that breaks your system. Please read up on [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) and [thread synchronisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Thread_or_process_synchronization).

Comment: @n.m. Even with thread locking which I removed from the version I posted here it still doesn't work.

Comment: A version with removed locks has no chance of being correct. Why should anyone waste time writing one, or looking at one?

Comment: You can use semaphores http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html

Comment: you have to create a lock for reading and writing to your list as said. If you use `printf()`in main and thread, and these might interfere, you need to create a lock for this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, you need locking around the list to make this correct.

However, the proximate cause of your problem is that `inet_ntoa()` returns a pointer to a statically-allocated buffer, which is overwritten on the next call.  You're recording a pointer to this buffer in your linked list, so the string pointed to by your linked list node changes when you next call `inet_ntoa()`.

You need to duplicate the string when you insert the node:

```
link->ip = strdup(ipaddr);
```

---

A simple approach the locking would be to create a global `pthread_mutex_t`:

```
pthread_mutex_t list_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

then lock it around the list check / insertion:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&list_lock);
if (checkInList(inet_ntoa(saddr.sin_addr)) == 1) {
    insertInList(inet_ntoa(saddr.sin_addr), 0);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_lock);
```

and around the sort / print:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&list_lock);
sort();
printInList();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_lock);
```

Comment: In `printInList()` I get a segfault at `printf("(%s:%d) ", /*PROBLEM*/ptr->ip/*?*/, ptr->count);` would that be because it is missing locking?

Comment: Yes, that is quite likely.  I've updated the answer to suggest one way in which you can add sufficient locking.

Comment: So I realized I was trying to copy a string to a int using the `int *tempIp` :/ Thanks for your help!